# MS chart control: hide default legend

Tags: mschart

I need to customize the legend of my MS chart control.
For that I am populating the CustomItems collection of the Legend.
That works fine.  However, when the legend is shown, the CustomItems info is appended to the Legend's default content.

How can I hide the Legend's default content ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

Chart1.Legends["Default"].Enabled = false;

Comment: Thank you !!  I wasted hours on this !!

Comment: Also, to hide each series in legend use this: `Chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;`